# How to escape "&" character in dryml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hobo

I've got this in my application.dryml file:

```
<def tag="googlemap">
  <html>
    <head>
      <style type="text/css">
        html { height: 100% }
        body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
        #map_canvas { height: 100% }
      </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAIbK8zw8fqY&sensor=false">
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        var georssLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://waterwatch.org.au/waterwatch_php/all_sites.php');
        georssLayer.setMap(map);
        }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
      <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"><div param="map" /></div>
    </body>
    </html>
</def>
```

I'm getting an error "Illegal character '&' in raw string" (the param separator in the maps.googleapis.com link.

How do I escape the & character in dryml?

Comment: src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAIbK8zw8fqY<%= "&" %>sensor=false">

seems to work... basically instead of & , it works if i use <%= "$" %>

is there a better way? seems a bit verbose

Comment: actually, hobo seems to be replacing <%="&"%> with "&nbsp;".

I wish hobo wouldn't keep getting in the way so much :P

Comment: ok great I managed it using the html_safe string function. To output a "&" character u have to enter <%= "&".html_safe %>